# Multiple variables and text in .appendChild()

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a table with a cell that has two 
buttons in it and a slash between them like [image: this]

```
function insertRow (label) {

    var list = document.getElementById('list');
    var row  = list.insertRow();
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var slash = document.createTextNode('/');
    var upButton = document.createElement('button');
    var  downButton= document.createElement('button');

            upButton.innerHTML = "Up";
            downButton.innerHTML = "Down";

    cell1.style.borderBottom = "2px solid black";
    cell1.style.borderLeft = "2px solid black";

    cell1.appendChild(upButton);
    cell1.appendChild(slash);
    cell1.appendChild(downButton);

}
```

The last 3 lines of this function do what I'm looking for but to me it doesn't seem like to correct way to do this. This is my first DOM scripting project.

Comment: That ***is*** the correct way to do this, good work !

Comment: @adeneo excellent! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We all live in the world of, "As long as the code works, it's good". However, few suggestions:

1. Not sure if JQuery is an option for you, but it can help develop browser independent code, else, you will end up testing this (javascript) code, in all browsers.
2. Create template HTML and append that to the cell. The number of lines of code will reduce drastically and the code becomes more readable.
3. Dont use inline styles. Instead, create a css class and use className method

Comment: Hi thanks for this, it's for a college assignment so JQuery is not an option at the moment, creating HTML template would be a lot easier but we have to focus on DOM scripting for this project. I'll defo look at css class method. Thanks again!